# Change language in Windows 10 initial setup

Tags: windows, windows-10, language, windows-installation, windows-installer

I just bought a new laptop with Windows 10 Pro in it and when I booted it up for the first time I got the Windows 10 initial setup guide in what appears to be Polish and I don't speak Polish:

[image: initial screen]

I don't see any option to change the language here. When I change the region to "United States", all subsequent screens remain in Polish.

I understand that I can change the language *after* the setup is done, but is there a way to do it *during* the initial setup?

Comment: What edition of Windows 10 did the machine come with? You would have to download a Windows 10 ISO with the appropriate language and install Windows over itself. You must be region where Polish is the primary language

Comment: It's Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Time to download a Windows 10 ISO for a language you can read in that case.

Comment: Download Windows in your preferred language. The license key should work in either case (otherwise a new Windows license cost only 10-20 $).