# How to change preinstalled win11 language (forever)? (before setup complete)

Tags: installation, windows-11, language, setup

i have some notebooks coming with a preinstalled win11, that is sadly in an unwanted language. is there a way to change the language of a preinstalled windows 11? (forever, so it stays when a system reset is done)?

maybe with WinPE?

background: i tried to install with a fresh win11 install media and remove all the preinstalled windows. sadly when i do this, win11 is not able to install because of missing drivers for the devices (e.g. wlan). then i tried to add some of the drivers with DISM but sadly they are not loaded. anyways better would be to change the preinstalled language as they are different models and might need different driver setups as well...
thats why i would like to change the preinstalled version for all time to englisch, so this problem is solved for next reset of the pc. any ideas that are not: "download another win11 and install"

very equal to this question but no answer then "install from another iso" what is not working for me.
[Change language in Windows 10 initial setup](https://superuser.com/questions/1696600/change-language-in-windows-10-initial-setup)

Comment: What's wrong with changing the language manually in *Settings  > Time & Language > Language*? It's permanent.

Comment: @harrymc ... the windows setup is never finished. its a fresh preinstalled version after purchase. i need a way to switch it before windows setup is done. for info: i have winPE i can boot into powershell from an usb-stick.

Comment: You were delivered a computer that can't do its first configuration (OOBE)? Or was OOBE never done before you tried to install Windows from boot USB?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1179311/windows-11-setup-without-internet

Comment: If you install the Polish version of Windows and choose the a different region, then the language will still be Polish, and the region will be whatever you selected. What you should do is download the correct English ISO and perform a clean install of Windows 11

Comment: @ChanganAuto thx for this post. yes indeed that is my problem. with a fresh win11 install stick i do not have any drivers, so i cannot even use the mice... and after install, i do not get any network, so i cannot finish the installation. ... that is the reason why i want to change the pre installed versions as they have the drivers ready. (and as i talk about more then just 1pc its not an option to create individual sticks with fitting drivers for every variant...)

Comment: @harrymc OOBE cannot/isnot finished as its all e.g. polish. as i know the users right, the pc's needs to be reset from time to time... when we then drop back to this original language we will begin again with this frustrating topic... already took me a day without any solution. i miss the times when i just put the floppy for dos...or when u could just add drivers via external media during installation...why they removed this?

Answer (score 0):

With Windows 11, you can slipstream drivers into the
release ISO the same as in Windows 10.
If you follow the procedure, and if the driver package
is suitable, this should be a reasonably straight process.

For details on the process see the Microsoft article
[Add and Remove Driver packages to an offline Windows Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-and-remove-drivers-to-an-offline-windows-image?view=windows-11).

Although the process is described in the above article with
detail, an even more detailed tutorial is found in the article
[Windows 11 with Driver Pack Slipstream](https://dellwindowsreinstallationguide.com/windows-11-direct-download/).

You may also consult the PowerShell scripts found in the
Github project
[Windows 11 Installation Media Slipstream Script](https://github.com/PhilipYip1988/Windows11Slipstream).

Comment: thanks @harrymc the first link is exactly with which i wasted a day without success.   is there a way to "slipstream" the drivers from the preloaded win11 to another win11 installation media? or change the language of the preinstallation?

Comment: You can export all drivers in elevated PowerShell with the command `Export-WindowsDriver -Online -Destination D:\Drivers`. It will create the folder.